# Union of two Non deterministic Finite automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How to perform union of two NFAs. This question is from Peter Linz's book.

Find an NFA with four states for $L=\{ a^n \ | \ n \geq 0 \} \cup \{b^n a \ | \ n \geq 1\}$.

Now Considering the first part as $L_1$ and second part as $L_2$ I am enclosing the solution.
The problem is I can't make out how strings like $\{\epsilon,a,aa,aaa,\dots\}$ are getting accepted in the final NFA.

Please help me to interpret the solution.

[image: Union of two NFAs]

Comment: What is your initial state?

Comment: If you want an automaton with one initial state, you should introduce a new initial state with $\epsilon$ transitions to both $A$ and $C$.  State $C$ can then be eliminated: the new initial state is directly connected to $D$ by a transition labeled $b$.  If the new initial state is made accepting, then the transition to $A$ can be labeled $a$, and the resulting automaton, while incomplete, is deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

To take the union of two NFAs, you just need to add an initial state with an $\epsilon$-transition to each of the initial states of the original NFAs. So if your $L_1$ and $L_2$ are

[image: L1 and L2]

you get

[image: with a common initial state]

That doesn't fully satisfy the requirements of the exercise, because you're supposed to have only 4 states. But because $L$ and $C$ have exactly the same incoming edges (i.e. none) and the same termination value (i.e. not accepting) we can merge them, eliminating the epsilon transition, to get

[image: Four-state solution]

In this particular case, it's also possible to eliminate the remaining epsilon transition:

[image: Four-state solution without epsilon transitions]

To make it a proper DFA, however, would require adding a sink state for the edges which are suppressed in the NFA:

[image: DFA with five states]

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to answer it for the general case.
Suppose you have $k$ NFAs (right, not necessarily DFA; of course, a DFA is a special case of an NFA), $N_1$ for $L_1$, $N_2$ for $L_2$, ... $N_k$ for $L_k$.
Just pose all automata together next to each other (even if they have states with the same names, copy everything).

Formally, Define an NFA N such that

- $Q = \bigcup_{1 \le i \le k} Q_i$
- $q_0 = {q_0}_i (\forall 1 \le i \le k)$ (Merge all the start states.)
- $F = \bigcup_{1 \le i \le k} F_i$
- $\delta(q) = \delta_i(q)$ where $i$ is the NFA to which this state ($q$) belongs.

  Note that by construction the destination states are also in $Q_i$.
- $\Sigma = \bigcup_{1 \le i \le k} \Sigma_i$

Effectively, each run is done inside one NFA. so if there is an accepting run, starting from $q \in Q_0$ and ending in $q' \in F$, then there must exists $i$ s.t. $q \in Q_i$, $q' \in F_i$, and all transition were performed according to $\delta_i$ using $\Sigma_i$, so $N_i$ accepts, so $w \in L_i$. So $L(N)$ is included in the union of $L_i$s.

Conversely, if $w$ in the union, then there exists $i$ s.t. $w$ in $L_i$ and there exists an accepting run in $N_i$, then the very same run exists also in $N$, so the union in $L(N)$. So $L(N) = \bigcup_{1 \le i \le k} L_i$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. In this answers, you have also used quite a few abbreveations, making it a little difficult to read.